# Problema "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out"

Tags: java, aplicación-web, webservice, email

Estoy trabajando con `WebLogic` y tengo un web service que retorna una lista de la base de datos y así mismo lo envía por e-mail (gmail).

El problema está en que, en mi ambiente local todo funciona muy bien, regresa la lista el web service y recibo el correo en mi bandeja de entrada.

En ambiente de producción recibo el error:

> "javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out"..

He intentado con el puerto 25 y de igual forma solo sirve en mi ambiente local.

También he probado con comandos `"telnet smtp.gmail.com 25"` desde mi server de producción y recibo respuesta del servidor de gmail.

¿Ideas? ,¿Qué podría hacer que no se pueda conectar al server smtp?

Adjunto mi código:

```
final String correo_remitente=prop.getProperty("correo_remitente");
final String password=prop.getProperty("password");
final String correo_destinatario=prop.getProperty("correo_destinatario");
final String server=prop.getProperty("server");
// get the property value and print it out
final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
// Get a Properties object
Properties props = System.getProperties();           
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", server);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");// tambien he puesto 465
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session2 = Session.getInstance (props, 
    new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(correo_remitente, password);
        }
    });
//Creamos el mensaje
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session2);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(correo_remitente));
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
InternetAddress.parse(correo_destinatario,false));
msg.setSubject("Mensaje de Prueba by Arthur");
msg.setText("Los siguientes artículos:\n"+x+" \n contienen errores, con fecha:"+ fecha.toString());
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
Transport.send(msg);
```

Las variables las obtiene de un archivo config y esta seteado para un correo saliente de G-mail.

```
password=********
correo_remitente=*******
correo_destinatario=*******
server=smtp.gmail.com
```

Comment: Estas usando SSL?, agrega tu código!

Comment: Ya lo he añadido! gracias!

Comment: comenta la línea solo como prueba : props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: He efectuado el cambio que sugieres y sigo recibiendo el mismo error :(

Answer (score -1):

Estas usando SSL ya que el mensaje indica el puerto 465, el puerto 465 es para [SMTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS):

> " javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp.gmail.com, port: 465; java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed
>   out"

Debes de probar directamente en el servidor de producción, debes asegurarte de estos 2 puntos:

- Revisar no tener bloqueado el puerto indicado, 465.
- Revisar tener permisos para smtp.gmail.com

Comment: He consultado con los administradores del server y me han mostrado que los puertos 25,465,587 estan desbloqueados... De hecho, no sé si el que pueda establecer una conexión telnet  me indica que efectivamente obtengo respuesta del servidor smtp de gmail porque como comentaba puedo establecer enlaces telnet a gmail

Comment: como prueba comenta : props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: He efectuado el cambio que sugieres y sigo recibiendo el mismo error :(